# Cycle elements in a python list at least once

Tags: python, loops, python-itertools

So I have a simple piece of code:

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0

players = [Player() for _ in range(10)]
```

Now I want to:

- Iterate the players in the list indefinitely
- Skip players with a negative score

```py
from itertools import cycle

loop = cycle(players)
loop = filter(lambda player: player.score >= 0, loop)
```

- Stop the iteration when there is only one player left with a positive score
- Or when there are two or more players with a positive score, **every one of them has been iterated at least once** and each of them has an equal score

I have a problem with these conditions and I don't know how to bite them.

Comment: The second condition kind of means that all the players have the same score, doesn't it?

Comment: Can't you just use some booleans? `While not (all_zero or ... or ...): player = next(loop)`

Comment: 2nd condition means every player in the list has either negative score or positive score equal to score of all other players with positive score. For example ```[-3, 5, 5, -1, -6, 5, -1, 5, -2, 5]``` would fit that condition. Main problem I have is with the part of the condition requiring to loop whole list at least once.

Comment: Do you consider 0 a positive number?

Comment: @Roy2012 yes, in my context 0 is positive score, because it allows player to stay in game.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Here's a solution using mostly `itertools`.

```
import itertools

positive_players = lambda : filter(lambda player: player.score >= 0, players)

loop = itertools.cycle(positive_players())

if len(list(positive_players())) <= 1:
    loop = positive_players()

if len(set([p.score for p in positive_players()])) <= 1:
    loop = positive_players()
```

Some tests:

- 3 players, all have score zero: stops after one loop.
- 3 players with scores [0, 42, 0]: continues forever
- 3 players with scores [-1, 42, -2]: stops after printing the one positive player.

### Solution 2

Here's an alternative solution, using a generator.

```
def loop_players(players): 
    inx = 0
    positive_count = 0
    positive_scores = set()
    while True: 
        p = players[inx]
        inx += 1
        if p.score < 0: 
            continue 
        positive_count += 1
        positive_scores.add(p.score)
        yield p 
        if inx == len(players):
            inx = 0
            if positive_count < 2: 
                break 
            if len(positive_scores) < 2:
                break
```

Comment: It's a function that returns a filter, not the filter itself. So the filter is recreated with every call.

Comment: Will the 2 in-line conditions in Solution 1 be evaluated at every iteration? Or just once?

Comment: Only once. They are evaluated once, and the loop is created based on that evaluation.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: No, sorry. I need to check stop conditions at every iteration. From what I understand, your Solution 1 would loop forever. I didn't look into Solution 2 yet.

Comment: @Kasia - you may want to actually run solution 1 (and solution 2), as neither of them loops forever. In solution 1, I take care of the case in which I need to stop *before* actually using the loop. In solution 2, I do it while using the loop. If you'd like, I can add a couple of examples.